# Intel Compiler: What does error "unknown type in IL walk" mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, icc

I tried the Intel compiler (icpc) for the first time on my project, which was developed using GCC.  After a few source files, it hits an error which does not tell me much:

```
/export/home/i11pcmh235/intel/bin/icpc -o .buildO/distmeasures/AlgebraicDistance.o -c -std=c++11 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/home/i11/cls/workspace/gtest/include src/distmeasures/AlgebraicDistance.cpp
src/community/PLM.cpp(147): internal error: assertion failed: unknown type in IL walk (shared/cfe/edgcpfe/walk_entry.h, line 1015)

            });
             ^

compilation aborted for src/community/PLM.cpp (code 4)
```

Can anyone explain it to me?

Are my compiler flags okay? I simply tried using the same ones as for GCC.

The code segment in question looks like this:

```
#pragma omp atomic read
                        C = zeta[u];

//                      TRACE("Processing neighborhood of node " << u << ", which is in cluster " << C);
                        G.forNeighborsOf(u, [&](node v) {
#pragma omp atomic read
                                D = zeta[v];
//                              TRACE("Neighbor " << v << ", which is still in cluster " << zeta[v]);
                                if (D != C) { // consider only nodes in other clusters (and implicitly only nodes other than u)
                                        double delta = deltaMod(u, C, D);
                                        if (delta > deltaBest) {
                                                deltaBest = delta;
                                                best = D;
                                        }
                                }
                        });
```

Comment: hey, just a quick question: what specific language (version, name, specification) is this?

Comment: @AnubhavSaini C++11. Including some OpenMP pragmas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internal error generally means that you've hit a compiler bug.  That is, the bug is in the compiler, not your code.  IL is compiler-writer speak for "Intermediate Language," the internal representation the compiler operates on to generate your code.

You'll have to see if Intel's fixed it, and/or file a bug report.

Comment: What is the proper way to report such a compiler bug?

Comment: I'm not sure with Intel's compiler.  It's been eons since I've used it, and never had to report a bug on it.  You might check around Intel's developer pages to see if there's a support link of some sort.  A quick google suggests this is a good starting point:  http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler